# Unix Process start by it self if it is down

Tags: unix

**Scenario:**

I have UNIX process myshellscript.sh , *By any reason if the sh script not running or stopped*, i want the process to be restarted.

**Note:** Don't want to use crontab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### shell script will be restarted with in 5 seconds if the process is down by any reason.

**01. Add service in /etc/systemd/system/**

**Example:**

```
vi  /etc/systemd/system/myshellscript.service
[Unit]
Description = SH Script
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5


[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart = sh /resource_path/myshellscript.sh



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**02. After creating command execute below commands**

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable myshellscript.service
systemctl restart myshellscript.service
```